# Dot product linear transformation proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

So the question asks: Prove that if $f : R^n$ to $R^n$ is a function such that $f(u) • f(v) = u • v$ for all $u,v  ∈ R^n)$, then f is a linear transformation. (Hint: for $c ∈ R$ and $v ∈ R^n$, what is the length of $f(cv)-cf(v)$?)

So take the hind so far I got:

For $c∈R$ and $v∈R$,

$f(cv)=cf(v)$

Suppose f satisfies the relation between the length and the dot product

$||v||^2=v•v$

then for any $u$ and $v$ in $R^n$,

$||f(u) - f(v)|| = ||u-v||$

when $v =0, ||f(u)|| = ||u|| $

when $u=0, ||f(v)|| = ||v||$

$(||f(u) - f(v)||) ^2=(||f(u) -f(v)||) (||f(u) - f(v)||)= ||f(u)||^2-2||f(u)||||f(v) +||f(v)||^2 =  ||u||^2-2f(u)f(v) + ||v||^2$

$(||f(u) f(v)||) ^2= ||u-v||^2= ||u||^2-2uv + ||v||^2$

Since $f(u)  • f(u) = u•u$  and $f(v)• f(v) = v•v$

So $-2f(u)f(v)=-2uv$

$f(u)•f(v)=u•v$

so $||f(u)-f(v)||^2= (f(u)-f(v))•(f(u)-f(v)) = f(u)•f(u)-2f(u)•f(u)+f(v)•f(v)=u•u-2u•v+v•v=(u-v)•(u-v)=||u-v||^2$

Therefore, f is a linear transformation.

Does this proof look right?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. Your reasoning seem to fail at going from $|f(u)-f(v)|^2 = |u-v|^2$ and from there conclude that it's linear. Why? Because $f(u)-f(v)=u-v$? That doesn't follow.

Instead you should use the hint, the length of $f(cv)-cf(v)$ can be calculated using dot product:

$$|f(cv)-cf(v)|^2 = (f(cv)-cf(v))\cdot(f(cv)-cf(v))$$

then using the property you will get to $|f(cv)-cf(v)|^2=0$. Doing the same trick with $f(u)+f(v)-f(u+v)$ will yield $|f(u)+f(v)-f(u+v)|^2=0$.

From these we could conclude that:

$$f(cv) = cf(v)$$
$$f(u+v) = f(u)+f(v)$$

which are the requirements of a linear function.

Answer (score 0):

So to prove $f$ is linear you have to show
$$f(cv)=cf(v)$$
which you have done, and
$$f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)\ ,\tag{$*$}$$
which I can't see anywhere in your answer.  To do this consider
$$\|f(u+v)-f(u)-f(v)\|\ ,$$
expand in terms of dot products and show that it is zero.  So pretty much the same as what you did with
$$\|f(cv)-cf(v)\|\ ,$$
I should imagine.